# Go bytes buffer - read from underlying preallocated byte slice/array

Tags: go, byte, buffer, writer

Can `bytes.NewBuffer(preallocatedByteSlice)` write to a byte slice/array accessible to the caller? We preallocate the slice to the size needed, so `bytes.Buffer` shouldn't be extending (and thereby replacing/reallocating) the underlying buffer. I'm aware that:

- https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer says "The new Buffer takes ownership of buf, and the caller should not use buf after this call." - sure, but not even for read only access on a byte slice that won't be extended/reallocated?
- `bytes.Buffer` has the `Bytes() []byte` method - but this would kinda complicate our project.

I've searched around a bit, but I'm getting a lot of results that don't quite answer my question; turns out generic words like "bytes" return a lot of results.

Here are some example code and output (https://play.golang.com/p/0TCy1qQF2Ek):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bs := make([]byte, 0, 4)
    fmt.Println(bs)
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(bs)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, []uint16{0xDEAD, 0xBEEF})
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(bs) // Would like to see [0xAD, 0xDE, 0xEF, 0xBE]
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes())) // prints addeefbe as expected.
}
```

```
[]
<nil>
[] // :(
addeefbe
```

Comment: You could keep reading from the buffer, but your problems are 1: the `bytes.Buffer` will re-allocate the buffer to a larger size whenever it wants, so you don't know if you're reading the right data, but you probably aren't after you start calling methods. 2: you would still need to synchronize reads with any writing done by the `bytes.Buffer` to avoid data races.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, we are already aware of the size of the data being read in, so we preallocate the byte slice to the exact needed size.

Comment: binary.Write uses an io.Writer as a target for two reasons: A) so that you can write data of "arbitrary" size to some io.Writer handling the result and B) if the target naturally _is_ an io.Writer already. None apply to your use case: If you _know_ the data beforehand just use the binary.Put* variants directly to your byte slice.

Comment: Read the documentation and source code for the `Bytes()` method and I think you'll find it is the most straightforward and correct solution to your problem here.  Also, the reason why 1st and 3rd print statements are empty is because your copy of the `bs` slice still has the length set as 0.  You can preallocate a large enough size, and indeed if you just add `bs = bs[:4]` after `Write`ing here you'll get what you want, but it's a terrible idea to rely on this.  The bytes buffer can reallocate internally whenever it wants.  The docs told you not to do this and offers a fine alternative method

Comment: @Volker really good idea, I had spaced that. Should solve my use case pretty elegantly.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco yeah, I get that doing anything outside of the interface contract is bad practice. Still, thanks for humoring me!